# Type conversion and method overloading

Tags: java, type-conversion, overloading

This is the sample code :

```
public class OverloadingExample {
public void display(Object obj){
    System.out.println("Inside object");
}

public void display(Double doub){
    System.out.println("Inside double");
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new OverloadingExample().display(null);
}
}
```

Output:

Inside double

Can anyone please explain me why the overloaded method with `Double` parameter is called instead of that with `Object` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - because `Double` is more specific than `Object`. There's a conversion from `Double` to `Object`, but not the other way round, which is what makes it more specific.

See [section 15.12.2.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5) of the JLS for more information. The details are pretty hard to follow, but this helps:

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error.

So here, any invocation of `display(Double doub)` could be handled by `display(Object obj)` but not the other way round.

Comment: Thanks . "The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error."

Comment: @noob: Yup, I was just adding that bit :)